# How can I use a function from my hook in a component file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I have two files, one is my hook for my react-table and the second file is a modal. My problem is I made a delete function in my hook and need to use that function in my modal file.

How can I choose a specific function to use in my component modal from my hook?

The hook file:

```
const useTableResource = () => {

const deleteButton = async (row) => {
    await axios.delete(`test/api/resources?_id=${row.original._id}`);
    console.log("deleted")
  };

  const DeleteHooks = (hook) => {
    hook.visibleColumns.push((colums) => [
      ...colums,
      {
        id: 'delete',
        accessor: () => 'delete',
        Cell: ({row}) => <div onClick={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}>
          <TrashButton/>
        </div>
        
      }
    ]);
  };

};

export default useTableResource;
```

The ModalComponent where I need to call the delete Button function:

```
const TrashModal = ({show, handleClose, handleConfirm}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose} className="Trashmodal">
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>attention</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Confirm </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer className="FooterTrash">
          <Button className="btn btn-sm" variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose} autoFocus={true}>Close</Button>
     
          <Button className="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onClick={//i need use here deleteButton function} autoFocus={true}>
            <i className="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>Confirm</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: 1. Your hook isn't a hook. 2. Just pull out the axios request into a separate function that accepts the necessary parameters and have both places call that function.

Comment: one way is to extract your function from the hook and export/import it as a regular function. Another way is to return it from the hook, and use it where you need it (although I would not recommend doing so). In general I'd personally suggest re-thinking the approach.